# Weird behavior on LIMIT and OFFSET when querying DBPedia

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia, virtuoso, rdflib

I'm querying DBPedia's Virtuoso endpoint via RDFLib in order to get all entities of type dbo:Politician with no other occupation than that, and I have noticed that the results I get when performing the query with increasing `OFFSET`s over the `LIMIT` (10000) doesn't contain all results

```py
def get_persons_for_occupation(occupation_URI):
    offset = 0
    limit = 10000 # DBPedia's Virtuoso SPARQL limit
    persons = []

    while True:
        g = Graph()

        try:
            query = """
                PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
                PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
                PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
                PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

                SELECT *
                WHERE {
                    SERVICE <https://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
                        SELECT ?person_with_occupation ?wikipedia_URL ?wikidata_URI
                        WHERE {
                            ?person_with_occupation rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* %s.
                            # TODO for debugging
                            # FILTER(regex(?person_with_occupation, "Trump"))

                            # Discard persons with an occupation (class) different than ours
                            FILTER NOT EXISTS {
                                ?person_with_occupation a ?other_occupation.
                                # That is not the occupation itself
                                FILTER ((?other_occupation != %s)
                                        &&
                                        # That is not a subclass of ours (* allows for indirect subclasses through the type hierarchy)
                                        NOT EXISTS { ?other_occupation rdfs:subClassOf* %s }
                                        &&
                                        # And that is a subclass of dbo:Person
                                        EXISTS { ?other_occupation rdfs:subClassOf dbo:Person })
                            }

                            # They have a Wikipedia article
                            ?person_with_occupation foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wikipedia_URL.

                            # And also an equivalent URI in Wikidata (in order to get its PageRank)
                            ?person_with_occupation owl:sameAs ?wikidata_URI.
                            FILTER (STRSTARTS(STR(?wikidata_URI), "http://www.wikidata.org"))
                        }
                        LIMIT 10000
                        OFFSET %s
                    }
                }
                """ % (occupation_URI, occupation_URI, occupation_URI, offset)

            qres = g.query(prepareQuery(query))

        except SPARQLResult as e:
            # Received correct but partial results (on the final offset), 
            # we don't want it to be an exception
            if e.response.status_code == 206:
                qres = JSONResultParser().parse(e.response.content)
            else:
                raise

        n_results = len(qres)
        if n_results == 0:
            break

        #for row in qres:
            #do stuff
        
        offset += limit
```

where `occupation_URI = "dbo:Politician"`

When collecting all results, I noticed that I got 27792 entities, but there are 74128 of them if I ask for a `COUNT` (especially, some entities such as Donald Trump's are not returned, but if I `FILTER` for it, it is returned). Is there a hard limit that I don't know of?

Comment: 1. proper pagination, and that's what you're trying to achieve with `LIMIT/OFFSET` needs `ORDER BY`

Comment: ignoring the 1.) point, and just assuming the implementation of the query evaluation is deterministic, 2.) the public Virtuoso endpoint has some anytime feature to return what ever it can compute in a given time

Comment: how did you count the results? I'm getting `159 040` on the public endpoint when doing `(COUNT(*) AS ?cnt)` instead. And I used a timeout of 0 which is more or less no query timeout.

Comment: @UninformedUser Oh...indeed, I was lacking the ORDER BY. Also for 2) true, I was executing it without a timeout. Now onwards to optimize it, because I'm hitting the maximum time limit with the non-count query. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused by the [Anytime Queries](https://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/anytimequeries/) feature / odd behavior / bug that lets Virtuoso return incomplete results without telling the client in a standards compliant way. That even happens inside of aggregations, which might explain varying COUNT results. (Detail can be found in the long and fruitless discussion at [openlink/virtuoso-opensource#112](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/112).) A client could recognize the incomplete result by checking for the HTTP response header `X-SQL-State: S1TAT`. (But which client already does that?)

In your case, I would simply change the last line of your code to increase the offset by the actual number of rows (binding) received:

```
        offset += n_results
```

Comment: Oh gosh, yeah. It ended up being a combination of this and what @Uninformed User pointed out (no ORDER BY clause). The DBpedia endpoint ended up being extremely unreliable due to these partial results...I managed to get all of them during a low server activity period, and for example this morning it was impossible to get even the first pagination. I ended up doing a similar query using Wikidata, which proved to be far more resilient. Thank you!